# No operations defined in spec! - I get this error even though the swagger is setup and the end points are defined

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-node-express

I am trying to setup swagger on top of my node application using the swagger npm package. I have my end points and swagger setup perfect(atleast almost perfect), I did do quiet a lot of research on whats going wrong but I couldn't find the trace. 
My swagger setup file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const abc= require('./routes/abc');
var app = express();

const swaggerDefinition = {
    info: {
        title: 'Analytics Project',
        version: '1.0.0',
        description: 'Analytics API swagger documentation'
    }
};
const options = {
    swaggerDefinition,
    apis: ['./routes/abc.js']
};

const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);

var api = require('./routes/abc');
app.use('/', api);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/api/v1/abc', abc);
app.use('/api/v1/abc/scatter', abc);
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));
module.exports = app;
```

My end points are defined in ./routes/abc.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = require('express').Router();
const request = require('request');

/**
 * @swagger
 * /:
 *   get:
 *     description:  Endpoint for everything
 */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) { //End point1
    res.send('hello from dataservice');
  });

/**
 * @swagger
 * /scatter:
 *   post:
 *    description:  Endpoint for all variations of scatter plots
 */
router.post('/scatter', function(req, res, next) { //end point2
    res.json({users: [{name: 'Timmy'}]});
  });
module.exports = router;
```

I was expecting the 2 end points to show up on the page. But instead I get the 'No operations defined in spec!' error. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 31):

It may be that there is an issue with how you are referencing your routes. The referencing must always start from the root of your application. So `'./routes/abc.js'` must be changed to `'the-folder-name-in-root/routes/abc.js'`

Comment: I made changes to path starting from root folder of project but i have still same issue

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: This is what I had to do as well. In my case, the main folder was being built from `/src` therefore my path would become "src/routes/*.js"

Comment: You fixed my day, thanks! My problem was that I had before two folders, one for server and another one for the client app, containing each their own `package.json` with their own commands to start each application. After moving those to root folder of my project, swagger stopped working cause the path was not taking that change into account. Thanks!

Comment: That was my issue as well and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Try change apis path from `apis: ['./routes/abc.js']` to `` apis: [`${__dirname}/routes/abc.js`] `` to make it the full path from the root folder. That works for me.

Comment: Pointing out this "apis" section sparked a fix for me.  I recently changed over to TypeScript and needed to update the "apis" path to end with *.ts.

Answer (score 5):

make apis full path like this `apis: [__filename],`
it work for me

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked when i added `paths` like below

```
 * @swagger
 * paths:
 *  /auth/login:
 *    post:
```

Answer (score 5):

I was getting same issue for fastify.
try to `require()` your routes after you register swagger.
And magically, it worked for me.
My case was:

> When I registered routes before swagger, it was showing 'no operations defined in specs':

```
fastify.register(require("./routes/route")); //registered routes BEFORE swagger
fastify.register(require("fastify-swagger"), {

exposeRoute: true,

routePrefix: "/docs",

swagger: {

info: { title: "SWAGGER API" },

}

});
//gave that issue with no warnings / errors in terminal or browser console
```

> This worked:  registering routes after swagger

```
fastify.register(require("fastify-swagger"), {

exposeRoute: true,

routePrefix: "/docs",

swagger: {

info: { title: "SWAGGER API" },

}

});

fastify.register(require("./routes/route")); //registered routes after swagger
```

Comment: No exposeRoute property anymore. Just remove exposeRoute and replace the swagger registration before the route registration line.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by changing URL from `"../api/controllers/userController.js"` to `"./src/api/controllers/userController.js"`.
So, you have to enter URL starting from root folder.

Answer (score 2):

What helped me in .NET 6 was that I forgot to specify that I'm using controllers. This little piece of code fixed my issue in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

Answer (score 2):

Always start referring from the root of the application.

[path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)

```
const path = require('path');

const options = {
    definition: {},
    apis: [path.join(process.cwd(), '/routes/*.routes.js')], 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe if you use a similar configuration you need specify the root package of project  "my.root.package"

```
@Bean
public Docket productApi(){
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
           .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.root.package")).build();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 6 don't forget to add

```
app.MapControllers();
```

along with

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

(as mentioned by Syscall)

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, I was able to solve it immediately I realise that I was referencing the wrong package.

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
   return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .select()
      .paths(PathSelectors.any())
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.korede.liberations"))
      .build()
      .apiInfo(apiDetails());
}
```

Just in case anybody is having this same issue, check the package you're referencing in your

`RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage()`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was on the packages. Swagger was not reading the controllers. I was using `springBoot` and `eclipse STS` as the IDE.

I had to:

1. Recreate each package from the base package.
2. Pull the right button over the base package, and select new packages one by one.
3. move each class to its package.

After that swagger shows the endpoints correctly.

Answer (score 0):

"No operations defined in spec!"

1. Please review the package versions in the Dependencies/Packages folder or in the .csproj file.
2. Update them to versions compatible with the current C# version.

Answer (score 0):

If your code has this line of code, remove it :

[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Name")]